# Prototype object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

When I make a prototype object, and use it for a new instance I should expect the name of the object is equal to how I called it. My prototype is called AUTO and the new one is called BMW

```
var auto = function(a,b,c) {

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;

};

var bmw = new auto("blue", true, 123);

console.log(bmw);
```

So the outpunt of this is: 
auto {a: "blue", b: true, c: 123}

But I expected 
BMW {a: "blue", b: true, c: 123}

However when I trigger this piece of code  console.log(bmw.a); i receive the correct value.

So my question is: Why is BMW = auto {a: "blue", b: true, c: 123} and not tot BMW {a: "blue", b: true, c: 123}

Comment: Your BMW is _an instance_ of the prototype `Auto`, not a new prototype. If you would chain _another_ prototype you could get it to be an instance of BMW, but in this case BMW is simply a specific instance of this 'class'.

Comment: `var vw = bmw; console.log(vw);` Now what?

Comment: @deceze big guy huh?

Comment: Think of my comment as a koan intended to poke you into the right direction of thinking.

Comment: @deceze I can appreciate that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BMW is an *instance* of your prototype `auto`. Its name, `BMW`, is just the *variable* in which this instance is stored. Try this for example:

```js
var auto = function(a,b,c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
};

var bmw = new auto("blue", true, 123);

document.write('<br />What is BMWs type? ');
document.write(typeof bmw);
document.write('<br />What is autos type? ');
document.write(typeof auto);
document.write('Is BMW an instance of auto? ');
document.write(bmw instanceof auto ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

In short, `bmw` is the variable that is holding an instance of your prototype `Auto` - it is *not* a new prototype. `Auto` is the constructor function - it's type is `Function`. Prototypes (or classes in different languages) are simply general objects that define the structure and methods of a certain object by default. For instance, you could make a prototype for 'vehicle', and then derive from those two prototypes for two-weeled vehicles and four-wheeled. Then you could make a new four wheeled vehicle, but this time you are making an *actual* vehicle, giving it a name, etc...

If you want to make a specific prototype for BMW, you should inherit it using the right methods:

```
var bmw = function(a,b,c) {
    // Using `call` will run the constructor of auto, with the context of `this`
    auto.call(this, a, b, c);
    // Then we can do prototype specific things here
    this.brand = 'BMW';
};
var bmw = new bmw("blue", true, 123);
```

Once you add prototype methods, btw, you will also have to use `Object.create(auto.prototype)` to chain it correctly.

Check out MDN for more information - have a good read there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain